# Knots bleeding through deck sealer

Tags: finishing, wood

I have a deck that I built in 1986 with treated lumber, that last year we used a stain sealer on and the sealer was bled thru at mostly knot locations.

I have used clear sealer many times over the years on this deck. You would think that as old as the wood is this should not happen. I scrubbed the deck with stiff bristle brush and a strong cleaner, heavy on bleach, and it looked good after applying stain sealer, but then in spring it showed many bare spots at the knots.

What can I do to rectify this?

Comment: Wood changes over time with weathering, UV exposure and heating and cooling cycles, you should expect it to be different now compared to how it was a few years back. I think fundamentally the issue is your sealer isn't on thick enough or just isn't good enough, i.e. it's not actually sealing the wood properly.